# SSL Certificate not configured Correctly

Tags: ssl

When I open my website on some wifi network it says SSL certificate not configured correctly and did not allow to proceed but when I switch my network like from wifi to hotspot / LAN it opens perfectly.

I am not able to figure out if ssl not configured correctly then it should remain same across network , why network switch works?

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to test your website on www.ssllabs.com and post here the result.

A tutoriel for install a SSL Certificate on Apache 2 : https://www.certificat-ssl.info/tutoriels/installer-certificat-ssl-apache-2-debian-ubuntu